# Javafx dynamically populate table rows and columnheads from sql query

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to populate data from database table to javafx table dynamically.
By using object of ResultSetMetaData, I tried to get names of columns of database table.
By using methods of ResultSet class, I want to populate javafx table.

I tried following way.

**Database Table**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcIbS.png)

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable 
{
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmt;

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TableView<?> tbl;
    private TextField tID;
    private TextField tName;
    private ComboBox<String> cmbType;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private Button btnDelete;
    private DatePicker tDate;

    public void refreshTable(Double[] widthArray)
    {
        TableColumn column;
        ObservableList row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        try
        {
            rs = db.stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp order by id");
            rsmt = rs.getMetaData();

            tbl.getColumns().clear();  
            for(int i=0; i<rsmt.getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                column = new TableColumn(rsmt.getColumnName(i+1));
                column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory(rsmt.getColumnName(i+1)));
                tbl.getColumns().add(column);

                column.setResizable(false);
                column.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbl.widthProperty().multiply(widthArray[i]));                    
            }

            tbl.getItems().clear();              
            while(rs.next())
            {
                for(int i=0; i<rsmt.getColumnCount(); i++)
                {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i+1));
                }
                data.add(row);
            }  
            tbl.setItems(data);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    { 

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        refreshTable(new Double[]{0.1,0.4,0.25,0.25});

    }
}
```

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="511.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="fxcrud.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="283.0" prefWidth="484.0" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS">
         <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="485.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView fx:id="tbl" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="296.0" prefWidth="480.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EsQ3.png)

Here you can see column headers are generated dynamically. But rows are not added.
What to do?

Comment: If you pass `"someProperty"` as parameter to `PropertyValueFactory`, it'll look for methods named `somePropertyProperty` or `getSomeProperty`. `List` has none of those. Furthermore you need to create one list per row, if you're using lists as items. Otherwise you've got the same data in every row and it contains all the values for every db row and column...

Comment: I just added line in the section of code to generate dynamic column. It worked.

col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                    }                    
                });